# How to open apps script File with DocumentApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs

im trying to create file with DriveApp from Blob like here

`var newfile = DriveApp.createFile(blob)`

and im trying to open this file with DocumentApp

`var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newfile.getId())`

But it seems id for this file for DriveApp is not the same as for DocumentApp. How could I get the right Id or open `newfile` with DocumentApp any other way?

Comment: I think that when you showed how you got the blob, it will help users think of the solution. Because the blobs retrieved by ``DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob()`` and ``DocumentApp.openById(id).getBlob()`` for file id of a document are automatically converted to "application/pdf". Such files cannot be opened by ``DocumentApp.openById(id)``.

Comment: What do you mean by "apps script File"? Is it a Google Apps Script standalone project?

Comment: When you create the new file, you should either use the Advanced Drive Service to create a Google Doc, or use DocumentApp to create the new file, and then set the content separately. `var doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name'); var body = doc.getBody();
 body.insertParagraph(0, blob.getDataAsString());`

Comment: By "apps script File" I mean class File https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file

Comment: Blob is craeted with `Utilities.newBlob()`

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in DocumentApp by it's URL. `File` objects have a method [getUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl) which can be used to retrieve the URL to open the file in a Google App; e.g.

```
var newfile = DriveApp.createFile(blob)
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(newfile.getUrl())
```